# Php-Ajax-JS Multiple Data Returns Problem

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

i have a problem.I am waiting for your help.Thank you

index codes are here.Even if i write dataType:JSON it didn't work.

index.php

```
function referansButon(sayfaNo)
       {
           $.ajax({
           url:"ajax.php",
           type:"POST",
                                   
           data:"action=referansButon&referansSayfano="+sayfaNo,
           success:function(data)
           {
               var result=$.parseJSON(data);
               alert(result[0]);
              alert(result["referanslar"]); // i know they are the same but i just wanted to see it if it 
                                          //is working
           }
                   
         });
      }
```

ajax.php

```
$referanslar="sdfdsfds";
$sayfalar= "sdfsdfdsfds";   //just for trying values.
$array=array("referanslar"=>$referanslar,"sayfalar"=>$sayfalar);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: What is returning any thing or just `null`

Comment: data variable is full but result variable is empty

Comment: Your getting values with wrong ways

Comment: And what kind of value is `data`?

Comment: clear your self with the answer below

Comment: @İrfan Sağdıç can your problem is solved or not??

Comment: @İrfanSağdıç is the problem solved or not?

Comment: @KUMAR notttttt

Comment: @MrPerfect not :(

Answer (score 2):

`data` is a string which is returning from `$.ajax` you convert the `string` to `json` and store in `var result` and after that you are using `data` again which is still string. update your code

```
var result=$.parseJSON(data);
```

and for first obj

```
alert(result.referanslar);
```

And for second obj

```
alert(result.sayfalar);
```

instead of `[0]` & `[1]`

Comment: json could not be converted to string ,                                                                                      i did what you trying to say but its same